# initialize matrix with vectors Python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I want to initialize a Matrix with 3 vectors. The special part about is that I want the vectors to be the columns the matrix.

```
Vx= np.zeros((npoints,))
Vy=np.zeros((npoints,))
Vz=np.zeros((npoints,))
V=np.matrix(([Vx,Vy,Vz]))
```

Now the problem here is that the vectors form the rows of the matrix.
How can I fix that?

Comment: From the docs, note that _"Despite its convenience, the use of the `numpy.matrix` class is discouraged"_

Answer (score 1):

You could use `np.column_stack`:

```
V = np.column_stack([Vx, Vy, Vz])
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a shorthand in numpy for this:

```
V = np.c_[Vx, Vy, Vz]
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative for unutbu solution is to use `np.vstack` or `np.hstack`

```
V = np.matrix(np.vstack((Vx, Vy, Vz)).T)
```